# Spring boot Controller returning null value to Thymleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbkLn.png)

[Controller Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ETTB.png)

[Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXfom.png)

I just can figure out what i am doing wrong the Controller class is loading to the Html page but it is still not showing model attribute , this is my first question on Stackoverflow sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please add your code directly in the post. Hod did you configure thymleaf ? See here for more infos : http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.Thymleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>Thymleaf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Thymleaf</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BootStrap and Jquery Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With the help of Maven Dependencies